# How to automate removal of a variable number of extra lines in datafiles?

Tags: python

I am using the phylogenetic program Bayestraits, which creates very large output files (10,000,000+ lines for thousands of columns), so I want to process files automatically without needing to open them. The output files are text files with spaces separating columns (when present). Additionally, the output files can have hundreds of lines of descriptors before the data actually begins that need to be deleted for the data to be analyzed.

In a simplified example, the output file might look like this:

> begin
> Extra line 1
> Extra line 2
> A    .B     . C     D #headers of actual data
> 1     30    34    3 #first line of actual data
> 2     33    30    3
> 3     31    39    4
> 4     28    42    2
> 5     25    37    4

In this simple case, only the first three lines need to be deleted, but in my cases this is a variable number of lines ranging from ~200 to ~800.

The first header is always "Iteration" ("A" in my dummy dataset), but the word iteration usually also appears in the extra lines that precede the data, and the number of "extra" lines before the data can vary. Is there a smooth way to transform many similar text files into .csv files that do not contain the lines preceding the headers and data?

I've been actively trying to do this in python, but I am beginner to this type of coding and am having trouble getting started. So far, I've been able to use sed to convert the files from .txt to .csv, but haven't been able to go further, using:

```
$ sed -r 's/[[:blank:]]+/,/g' input.txt > output.csv
```

Thank you so much for any feedback or help, I'm sure this is a pretty basic solution, but I have been struggling to figure it out for a while.

Answer (score 0):

You might be better off loading the file as a regular text file, preprocessing it, then make it into a pandas DataFrame and finally save it as a csv.

I'll make an assumption, clarify if I'm wrong about this, but I assume the extra lines all begin with text. If so, you can open the file

```py
with open("file.txt") as f:
   lines = f.readlines()
```

Then you can iterate through and see where the numeric data begins

```py
data_start = 0
for index, data in enumerate(lines):
    try: 
        num = int(data.split(" ")[0])         # attempt type coercion        
    except ValueError:
         continue               # move on to next
    else:
        data_start = index - 1  # this will include column titles
        break
```

Then set the remaining list to a pandas DataFrame and save to csv

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(lines[data_start:], columns=lines[0])
df.to_csv("file.csv", index=False)   # unless you want to keep the index
```

Comment: Do **not** use bare imports ([PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#id49)). At most, catch all non-exit exceptions with `except Exception`. Though in this case you know exactly the exception to be caught, that is `ValueError`. Also, limit the `try` block to only the line that should raise the exception.

Comment: Another thing is, wouldn't the type casting always fail if there is anything else in the line besides one single continuous integer (which seems to be the case)? I made a suggestion to address that.

Comment: Nice catches. Agreed on all accounts.